# Is .Net reading web.config from top to bottom?

Tags: .net, asp.net, configuration, web-config, configuration-files

1) If ( inside *web.config* file )  I declare custom section named *songPoem* before `<configSection>` , an error is reported saying *songPoem* element is not recognized. Thus, the following gives me an error:

```
<songPoem song=”lalala” />

<configSection>
  <section name=”songPoem” type=”A” />
</configSection>
```

while the following works just fine:

```
<configSection>
  <section name=”songPoem” type=”A” />
</configSection>

<songPoem song=”lalala” />
```

A) I assume error is due to .Net reading `web.config` from top to bottom?! If so, is the order of element declaration an issue only when it comes to custom section elements, or...?

BTW - here's the definition for class A:

```
public class A: ConfigurationSection
{
   [ConfigurationProperty(“song”)]
     public string Song{ ... } 
}
```

2) I would assume that only *song* attribute would be allowed inside `<songPoem>` element, and thus I would expect that .Net would be able to notice if custom section element includes any non existing attributes. But for some reason I was able to include other attributes also, even though they don’t map to any property of class *A*:

```
<songPoem song=”lalala” movie=”this_should_be_here” />
```

Any idea why Net didn't notice that *songPoem* contains an invalid attribute?

Answer (score 2):

I did quite an extensive blog post on custom configuration sections a while back to clear up my own confusion about them.  That should give you some pointers to help you get it sorted out:

http://www.endswithsaurus.com/2008/11/custom-configuration-section.html

Comment: I checked your link, but couldn't find anything that would explain with which elements the order of declaration is important. I also couldn't find any explanation on why Net doesn't notice non existing attributes

Answer (score 1):

I've always setup my web.config like so:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="myConfigGroup">
            ....
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <myConfigGroup>
        ....
    </myConfigGroup>
</configuration>
```

Never had any problems.  It truely made me nuts when I made the same mistake as you and couldn't understand what the issue was.

Answer (score 0):

well, it uses an xmlreader to read the data, so I would imagine it reads top down, and processes the elements it finds in order.

Though i would suspect it to do a double-pass to support issues like this.  I guess it doesn't.

Also, i've always seen a standard practice of declaring config sections at the top, perhaps this is why.

Technically order matters too, because just as with deserialization, i would expect the objects in a list to be deserialized in the same order they were defined.